# Unexplainably incredible performance with Pythagorean triples in Haskell

Tags: performance, haskell

Let's say we have this simple Haskell function that produces Pythagorean triples:

```
pytha :: [(Int, Int, Int)]
pytha = [(x, y, z)
        | z <- [0..]
        , x <- [1..z]
        , y <- [x..z]
        , x * x + y * y == z * z
        ]
```

and we'd like to benchmark how long does it take to produce, say, first 100 triples. So (using the `criterion` library and assuming `import Criterion.Main`) we have this benchmark:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  countStr <- readFile "count.txt"
  defaultMain [ bgroup "pytha" [ bench countStr $ nf (`take` pytha) (read countStr) ] ]
```

where we even read the `count` from a file to make sure ghc does not try to evaluate `pytha` during compile time!

Doing `echo 100 > count.txt`, compiling the benchmark with `-O2` and running on my machine (a 4.0 GHz Sandy Bridge CPU) shows some interesting numbers:

```
time                 967.4 ns   (957.6 ns .. 979.3 ns)
                     0.999 R²   (0.998 R² .. 0.999 R²)
mean                 979.6 ns   (967.9 ns .. 995.6 ns)
std dev              45.34 ns   (33.96 ns .. 60.29 ns)
```

Slightly modifying this program to show how many triples were considered overall (by producing all the triples first, zipping the list with `[0..]` and then filtering out all non-Pythagorean triples and looking at the indices of the resulting ones) shows that almost 900000 triples were considered.

All this naturally raises the question: how does the code above manage to achieve 1000 triples/ns on a single core of a pretty standard CPU? Or is it just that my benchmark is wrong?

Comment: Wild guess: lazy execution and memoization.  Haskell is pretty good at this sort of thing, if you present it a problem that is tractable in this way.

Comment: `nf` in the benchmark should account for lazy execution if I understand correctly. But how do I make sure memoization does not take place in this case?

Comment: Why would you want that?

Comment: In general, indeed, that's generally a good thing. But in this case looks like it kills the benchmark.

Comment: No.  Memoization is a legitimate technique.  You're basically saying the Lakers didn't win the game because he threw the ball from midfield, so it doesn't count.

Comment: Agreed, it's a legitimate technique, but it doesn't help measuring how much the first run did take, which is exactly what I want to do here.

Comment: In this case, memoization indeed invalidates the benchmark, as far as I can see. Try adding a dummy argument, e.g. `pytha () = ...` so that it becomes a function and memoization does not happen.

Comment: @chi thanks for the suggestion! I've just tried that, and it doesn't significantly change the numbers.

Comment: @chi, that's not enough to fool the optimizer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a function rather than a value that will be memoized.

```
pytha :: Int -> [(Int, Int, Int)]
pytha z_max =
    [ (x, y, z)
    | z <- [0..z_max]
    , x <- [1..z]
    , y <- [x..z]
    , x * x + y * y == z * z
    ]
```

GHC isn't going to get clever enough to factor this into `takeWhile` from a constant list, so it should give a meaningful benchmark. Just make sure Criterion is in charge of passing `z_max`, which you can reasonably set to `maxBound :: Int` or some such.

By the way: you can make your implementation much less slow by using floating point operations to calculate much tighter bounds for `y`.

Comment: Aha, this way I've got 1.3 ms and this makes way more sense now, thanks! Interestingly, indeed, writing the benchmark as `nf (\n -> take n $ pytha maxBound) (read countStr)` does not work: ghc is still able to memoize. I had to do `nf (\(n, m) -> take n $ pytha m) (read countStr, maxBound)`, just as you suggested.

Comment: BTW is there anything worth reading about this behaviour, or is it such a deep internal detail of ghc optimizer that it doesn't make much sense to describe and formalize it?

Comment: @0xd34df00d, you should even be able to get away with `nf (take 100 . pytha) maxBound`.

Comment: @0xd34df00d, you should probably search for "constant applicative form" (and also general info on the mechanics of lazy evaluation) for why your original approach didn't work, and for "full laziness" and probably "constant lifting" to see why some simpler modifications (like the one chi suggested) don't work.

Comment: I'm a bit scared now :) I thought GHC was quite conservative to lift constants over lambdas (full laziness producing CAFs). But it is no longer so. I recall the reason was that doing that could make CAFs cause a memory leak: when the function returns, normally the memory could have been GC'd, but now the list is a CAF so it stays there forever. Wow, this got much trickier.

Comment: @chi, I'm not really sure what GHC's rules/heuristics are for that. I haven't heard of it getting *more* aggressive--maybe less so. But it does lift a lot of "obvious" things like this.